# Python Docx Minimum Table Height

Tags: python, docx

I'm trying to fit 10 rows (and three columns) of a table on one page, howver I'm running into a limitation where I can't get any more than 8 rows to fit.  I've tried the following code:

```
table = document.add_table(rows=0, cols=3)
for row in table.rows:
    row.height = Cm(1)
```

However, at some point when reducing the size,there is no difference in the output. Is it possible to fit 10 rows on one page?

An adapted version of my code, which is iterating through a dataframe and writing columns of my dataframe to cells of a table.

```
document = Document()
sections = document.sections
for section in sections:
    section.top_margin = Inches(0.00)
    section.bottom_margin = Inches(0.00)
    section.left_margin = Inches(0.00)
    section.right_margin = Inches(0.00)
style = document.styles['Normal']
font = style.font
font.size = Pt(8)
table = document.add_table(rows=0, cols=3)
index = 0
full_count = 1

for item_one, item_two,description,max_portion,quantity_adjusted, mods in zip(line_items['title'].tolist(), line_items['quantity'],line_items['description'], line_items['max_portion'],line_items['quantity_adjusted'], line_items['modifications']):
    count = 0
    if index % 3 == 0:
        cell_row = table.add_row()
        cell_row.height = Cm(0.1)
        row_cells = cell_row.cells
        part_one_cell = row_cells[index % 3]
        part_one_cell.height = Cm(0.1)
        #para = doc.add_paragraph().add_run('GeeksforGeeks is a Computer Science portal for geeks.')
        #para.font.size = Pt(12)
        p = part_one_cell.add_paragraph()
        p.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.CENTER
        #p1 = part_one_cell.paragraphs[0].add_run(item_one.upper()+ ' ' + description.upper())
        #p1.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.CENTER
        if len(item_one + description) < 40:
            p.add_run(item_one.upper()+ ' ' + description.upper()).font.size = Pt(12)
        elif len(item_one + description) < 60:
            p.add_run(item_one.upper()+ ' ' + description.upper()).font.size = Pt(10)
        else:
            p.add_run(item_one.upper()+ ' ' + description.upper()).font.size = Pt(8)
        row1 = row_cells[index % 3]
        row2= row1.add_paragraph(mods)
        row2.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.CENTER
        row = row_cells[index % 3]
        p1 = row.add_paragraph(f'{x[str(quantity_adjusted)]}')
        p1.alignment=WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.RIGHT
        #part_one_cell.paragraphs[0].add_run(f'{x[str(item_two)]}')
        #part_one_cell.paragraphs[0].add_run(f' {str(x)}').bold= True
        index = index + 1
        full_count = full_count + 1
        if full_count % 30 == 0:
            document.add_page_break()
            table = document.add_table(rows=0, cols=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no problem getting 10 1cm rows in a single page. I declare the number of rows when adding the table:

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Cm
document = Document()
table = document.add_table(rows=10, cols=3)
table.style = 'Table Grid'
for row in table.rows:
    row.height = Cm(1)

document.save('demo.docx')
```

To add rows in a for loop:

```
table = document.add_table(rows=0, cols=3)
table.style = 'Table Grid'
for i in range(10):
    row = table.add_row()
    row.height = Cm(1)

document.save('demo.docx')
```

[image]

Comment: What if you don't know the size of the table in advance?  And are having to add_row to a table within a for loop?

Comment: @ben890 I added an example of adding rows to a table in a for loop

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure exactly what's going on wiht my code then.  I'm editing my question to show an adapted version of my code.  I'm trying to have 30 cells per page (10 rows, 3 columns) and add a page break when I hit 30.

Comment: What is the problem with the code you added? Do you have a specific question?

Comment: Only up to 8 rows can fit per page.

Comment: I'm not sure why but no matter how small I make the row height I can still only get 8 rows to fit

Comment: Can you share a screen grab? Have you tried making the font smaller?